# DSE Graph authentication error

Tags: graph, datastax-enterprise, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

On a fresh new installation, DSE Graph throws an error to Gremlin Console, complaining about authentication configuration.

Gremlin Console starts normally:

```
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph 
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server 
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities 
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==>Configured cassan-1-vm.c.myklovr-dev.internal/10.128.0.4:8182
```

but when you try any operation against Gremlin Server, you get an error:

```
    gremlin> :> 1+1 
ERROR 18:11:25,717 Could not process the response javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failure to initialize security context
            at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.<init>(GssKrb5Client.java:149) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
            at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.FactoryImpl.createSaslClient(FactoryImpl.java:63) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
            at javax.security.sasl.Sasl.createSaslClient(Sasl.java:384) ~[na:1.8.0_101] ... Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
            at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5NameElement.getInstance(Krb5NameElement.java:129) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
            at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getNameElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:95) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
            at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getNameElement(GSSManagerImpl.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
            at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.getElement(GSSNameImpl.java:477) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
            at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.init(GSSNameImpl.java:201) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
            at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.<init>(GSSNameImpl.java:170) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
            at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createName(GSSManagerImpl.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
            at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.<init>(GssKrb5Client.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
            ... 27 common frames omitted Security error - check username/password and related settings
```

Question is: how to overcome this error?

This has already been tried:

1. De-activate Kerberos authentication in dse.yaml
2. Reset krb5.conf to a default file (the one in the DSE sandbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could not find a casuistic explanation for this.

As a workaround, we installed again from the datastax installer (instead of yum) and this problem did not happen.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem too. The way I solved was by explicitly putting username and password.
Ensure that your remote.yaml file dse/resources/graph/gremlin-console/conf/ has a structure similar to this.

You do not need to restart for it to take effect.

`hosts: [localhost]
port: 8182
username: cassandra
password: cassandra
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0,
              config: { serializeResultToString: true, ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistry] }}
connectionPool: {
  maxContentLength: 65536000, enableSsl: false
}`

Also listed here:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/sec/graphSec.html
The three attributes I changed from the default remote.yaml are username, password, enableSsl